# Параллельное программирование POSIX

Tags: c, unix, posix

Что делает sem_wait простыми словами?

Comment: https://it.wikireading.ru/24890

Comment: Довольно много информации в интернете написаной доступным языком и с множеством примеров, начиная от дверей туалета до ядерных реакторов. Что именно Вы не можете понять в работе `sem_wait`?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/261273/ - Такие удивительные семафоры

Comment: Я благодарю вас за ответы, я прочитал все снова и все понял.